# String index out of range issue in

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've made this simple script for practicing RegEx that is supposed to read text that I copied to the clipboard and count how many times the word "corona" is mentioned. But i keep getting

> "IndexError: string index out of range" which I get at   `matches.append(groups[0])`

which I don't understand seeing as I'm starting the index at 0.

```
import re
import pyperclip

coronaRegEx = re.compile(r'Corona(virus)*', re.IGNORECASE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
count = sum(matches)

for groups in coronaRegEx.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy(join(matches))
    print("Found " + count + " of instances")
else:
    print("No instances found")
```

Comment: Hint: The empty string has not content at index `0`.

Comment: Can you point on which line you are getting the error?

Comment: I guess the error comes from `matches.append(groups[0])`, right? That's because you might get a result from findall that is an empty string which, of course, can't be used with `[0]`.

Comment: I don't follow. If the result from findall is an empty string shouldn't it print "No instances found"? But it should have content though I've typed the word "corona" and copied it...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your approach about the problem. I have simplified into following

```
import re
#import pyperclip
#I don't know what clipboard pasting you are doing so I have skipped pyperclip 
text = "Corona(virus) adsfj rl Corona adfs Corona adf Corona dfsd Corona Corona(virus) dfs asdf"
matches = []

for group in re.findall('Corona[virus]*',text):
    matches.append(group)

print(matches)

if len(matches) > 0:
    print("Found " + str(len(matches)) + " of instances")
else:
    print("No instances found")
```

see If this solves your problem. (this also handles empty string corner case)